# How do I export a column of email addresses from a sql server report to Outlook's To: field?

Tags: t-sql, email, visual-studio-2012, outlook, business-intelligence

I'm looking to add a button to my published report that would export all of the email addresses in a particular column of the report directly to outlook and place it in the "To:" field of an email.

My report was created through Visual Studio 2012 using the Business Intelligence Services reports, and is based on a series of stored procedures in t-sql to create unique parameterized sub reports.

As of now, every aid source I've found has exporting to Outlook from an excel file, but I'm looking to do it directly from the report.

Any help would be really appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is add a reference in your project to either the Outlook Object Model COM object or the Interop assembly (somewhere in 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office15\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll", for example).

You can then create an instance of the Outlook.Application object and call Application.CreateItem to get a MailItem object.  Use MailItem.To to add the email address.

Application.CreateItem method:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ff869635.aspx

Automating Outlook from Other Office Applications:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869289.aspx

Note that calling MailItem.Send may display a warning. See this for security considerations:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms772422.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#officeoutlook2007whatsnewdeveloperspart1__security

Comment: I believe this is going to wind up as my solution, but alas, I don't have the reputation required to vote this as my answer. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome! Good grief I didn't realize posters can't even vote for an answer to their own question!

Comment: Sadly not until we hit Rep 15, I was close, but got down-voted last minute and didn't have enough to vote you my answer

Answer (score 0):

So another possible solution I discovered is to link the text-box to an action, and use the mailto: action.

First I created a parameter that could contain multiple values. I populated the parameter with the contents of the email field that was pulled into my report.

Then I edited by textbox action. By putting the first address in the to: field, and the remaining email addresses in the bcc: field this accomplished what I was looking to do. It looked a little like:

```
="MailTo:" & First(Fields!email.Value, "DataSet1") & "?bcc=" & replace(join(Parameters!EmailList.Value, ","), (First(Fields!email.Value, "DataSet1") + ","), "")
```

To roughly explain what it does further, my people can opt to not supply an email address. I changed all these values from null to blanks in the back end, and chose to allow blanks for the parameter. The join creates a comma separated list of email addresses, and the replace both removes a blank email, as well as removes the first email address in the list so I don't double email that person.